# Is it possible for contents in a nav bar to act as buttons not links

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to keep my buttons concise inside a menu nav bar but I noticed most of the contents in the nav bar act as links, I want to store table in my buttons, inside the nav bar. I don't know if this is possible or sensible. I am really new at this..............................................................

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
     top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

 .overlay .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 60px;
}

   @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
   .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;
</a>
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>

 <h2>Fullscreen Overlay Nav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the fullscreen overlay navigation menu.</p>
<p>In this example, the navigation menu will slide in, from left to right:
</p>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>

<script>
function openNav() {
document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "50%";
}

function closeNav() {
document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use button instead of <a> or apply css like button to <a>

Comment: So you'd like your text links to be buttons, but still look like text?

Comment: @sconner87 yes,that's what I want

Comment: @lloyd why not just use text then? o.0 I am confused. Why do you want a button that looks like text but dont want to use text?

Comment: @lloyd : see I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you what you need.  Change your menu links to

```
<div class="overlay-content">
<button class="buttonStyle" href="#">About</button>
<button class="buttonStyle" href="#">Services</button>
<button class="buttonStyle" href="#">Clients</button>
<button class="buttonStyle" href="#">Contact</button>
</div>
```

Then add the following to your style.

```
.buttonStyle {
padding: 8px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 36px;
color: #818181;
display: block;
transition: 0.3s;
background-color: transparent;
border: 0;
outline: 0; 
position: relative;
top: 25%;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 30px;
}
.buttonStyle:hover {
color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

All we've done here is changed your `<a>` tags to `<button>` tags and styled your button so it appears the same as your text links. Hope this helps.

Edit: You will need to edit your media query to add responsiveness again :)

```html
<style>
body {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
     top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

 .overlay .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 60px;
}
.buttonStyle {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0; 
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.buttonStyle:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

   @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
   .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}
</style>
<body>

<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;
</a>
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <button class="buttonStyle" href="#">Services</button>
    <button class="buttonStyle" href="#">Clients</button>
    <button class="buttonStyle" href="#">Contact</button>
  </div>
</div>

 <h2>Fullscreen Overlay Nav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the fullscreen overlay navigation menu.</p>
<p>In this example, the navigation menu will slide in, from left to right:
</p>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>

<script>
function openNav() {
document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "50%";
}

function closeNav() {
document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
}
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: [I've been told to create a “runnable” example with “Stack Snippets”, how do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/402037)

Comment: Fixed, my bad. Sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

See, here I've the working snippet, you can change color and padding /margin for button class according to you.

```js
function openNav() {
document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "50%";
}

function closeNav() {
document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
}
```

```css
.button {
    display: block;
    width: 115px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left : 100px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
     top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}



 .overlay .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 60px;
}

   @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
   .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>


<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;
</a>
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#" class="button">About</a>
    <a href="#" class="button">Services</a>
    <a href="#" class="button">Clients</a>
    <a href="#" class="button">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>

 <h2>Fullscreen Overlay Nav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the fullscreen overlay navigation menu.</p>
<p>In this example, the navigation menu will slide in, from left to right:
</p>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
```

Comment: @Andreas: thanks for the suggestions, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add .btn class to your link and add some styles. With :active selector, you can add click effect like standard button - for example: inset shadow.

```
.overlay a.btn {
    background: #818181;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 36px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 17px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: normal;
}
.overlay a.btn:active {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
}

<a href="#" class="btn">About</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this if you wan't to keep your links for some reason:

```
<!DOCTYPE>

<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="hRefClick(event);">alikn</a>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    function hRefClick(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("redirection prevented");
    }
</script>
```